# How to handle pointless answers when reviewing?

Tags: discussion

The "Late answers" queue often contains answers that are pointless: 5 years later, the software has likely changed and the question may already have accepted answers.

- flag for deletion (VLQ? INOMI?)
- don't do anything and hope it gets voted out
- if the question is that old, who really cares?

Comment: VLQ = posts that aren't any legit type of post (question, answer, comment), have no value, & aren't salvageable (ex: gibberish, rant). Why it's pointless matters. Duplicates existing answer? Non-responsive to the question? Pabulum, comment, speculation, or non-actionable suggestion? Just a link? If it's simply a poor suggestion, or not as good as what's already posted (or even technically incorrect), it's still a legit answer, just not a useful one. Generally, downvote for quality issues, flag for posts that shouldn't be on the site because they don't meet the definition of an acceptable post.

Comment: I have found old questions that have incorrect answers marked. If I am actively looking to solve a similar problem then the question is still valid and helpful to me. I might come back and post the real answer if I find it elsewhere. This is because I was routed here first by google so other people who end up in the same place will find the answer I found later without doing the additional research I did.

Comment: I'm not saying that all late answers are pointless... just that many are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it a valid (good) answer, then don't do anything (except maybe upvote).

If it is a bad answer, then downvote, and maybe cast an appropriate flag.

Please read [Guidelines for reviewing Late Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/267099)

Comment: No VTC on answers, it would have to be a flag for <20K users.